# How to back-up and then delete ~525,000 Tasks easily?

Tags: tasks, delete, data-storage, backup

My Company is currently at a point where we need to clean up some data to make sure we don't exceed our storage limits.

I've run the numbers and would need to remove ~525,500 tasks to clear out the majority of our data.

These are all older completed tasks.

What would be the easiest way to back these up and remove them from Salesforce?

Comment: Export and delete using data loader

Comment: @Eric Can the data loader handle that much? And how can I delete using the Data Loader?

Comment: Back it up for historical data, and use data loader

Comment: @CodyBeaner dataloader works in batches of 200 so sure it will work, who knows how long it will take

Comment: @EricSSH - Data Loader in bulk API mode can be very fast. I killed off 150,000 Leads the other day in a reasonable (<1 hr) time

Comment: Oh ya for sure,  I meant it more as just plan accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Using the Salesforce DataLoader will enable you to extract all desired task records with all associated attributes.

Once the extraction step is complete you need only run a delete job against the activity record ids that you extracted in the first step and the job is done.

Comment: How can I run the delete with no limit issues? Can I do this with the Data Loader?

Comment: Should be fine. Run dataloader in bulk api mode, and if you find that there are triggers on task delete that blow your governor limits, reduce the chunk size - both using bulk api mode and chunk size settings are in the settings area of DataLoader.